# como puedo pasarle un objeto a un componente?

Tags: react-native

Buenas estoy teniendo el siguiente error en mi app cuando paso un objeto a un componente:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child
```

Y luego este screense lo quiero pasar a mi componente

EventScreen.js:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const EventScreen = () => {

    const eventsMenta = [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Evento Menta',
        date: new Date(2022,4,31)
        }
      ]

  return (
    <View>
      <EventItem
        title={eventsMenta[0].title}
        date={eventsMenta[0].date}
      
      ></EventItem>
    </View>
  )
}

export default EventScreen
```

y aca se encuentra el componente al que le estoy pasando a mi screen:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const EventItem = (props) => {


  
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.title}</Text>
      <Text>{props.date}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default EventItem
```

Esta sería mi navigation donde a partir de mi login quiero pasar a la screen del evento:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React from 'react'
import SignInScreen from '../src/screens/SignInScreen/SignInScreen';
import EventScreen from '../src/screens/EventScreen/EventScreen';


const Stack  = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MainStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen
                name = "Login"
                component = {SignInScreen}
            />

            <Stack.Screen
                name = "Events"
                component = {EventScreen}
            />

        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default MainStack
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para resolver este error ya que no me deja pasarle el objeto a mi componente.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es que no puedas pasarle un objeto a un componente como `props`. De hecho, estás teniendo este error porque estas tratando de renderizar un objeto dentro de `Text`. Esta linea en particular es la que genera problemas

```
<Text>{props.date}</Text>
```

En su lugar, debes determinar lo que quieres mostrar. Por ejemplo, puedes hacer

```
<Text>{props.date.toLocaleString()}</Text>
```

Lo anterior retorna un texto representativo de la fecha, aunque probablemente quieres lograr algo diferente. Ver [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)